# How can I take a picture with an .png image on it

Tags: android, camera, png, surfaceview

I've created an camera application which has an image on camera preview. This is image is a hat, for example, and I want to take an photo of an person with the hat image over his head. This is what I've done:

```
        mFrameLayout = new FrameLayout(this);

        mPreview = new Preview(this);
        mFrameLayout.addView(mPreview);

        mImage = new ImageView(this);

        FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100);
        layoutParams.leftMargin = 200;
        layoutParams.topMargin = 100;
        mImage.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        mImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.gorro);
        mFrameLayout.addView(mImage);

        mFrameLayout.setOnClickListener(this);

        setContentView(mFrameLayout);
```

Preview Class:

```
class Preview extends ViewGroup implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private final String TAG = "Preview";

    SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
    SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    Size mPreviewSize;
    List<Size> mSupportedPreviewSizes;
    Camera mCamera;

    Preview(Context context) {
        super(context);

        mSurfaceView = new SurfaceView(context);
        addView(mSurfaceView);
    }
```

And this class has all the surface methods implemented. 
When I touch on any place on the Camera, the photo is taken. Here's the code:

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Taken!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        mCamera.takePicture(null, mPictureCallback, mPictureCallback);
    }

    Camera.PictureCallback mPictureCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] imageData, Camera c) {
            if (imageData != null) {
                String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        .toString();
                File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images2");
                myDir.mkdirs();
                Random generator = new Random();
                int n = 10000;
                n = generator.nextInt(n);
                String fname = "Image-" + n + ".jpg";
                File file = new File(myDir, fname);
                if (file.exists())
                    file.delete();
                try {
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    out.write(imageData);
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();
                    Log.d("teste", "onPictureTaken - wrote bytes: "
                            + imageData.length);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

The problem is when I take an photo with the .png image, the photo is saved without it.

How can I also save the .png image when photo is taken ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert your imageData to Bitmap in PictureCallBack and then use a Canvas with method drawBitmap to draw your hat bitmap onto the captured image from Camera. Finally you can save result bitmap to a file.
So:

```
Bitmap cameraBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageData, 0, imageData.length);
Canvas canv = new Canvas(cameraBitmap );
canv.drawBitmap(.... your hat image);
```